# Load iframe website in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load a seperate website (eg. a wikipedia article) in an iframe on a web page. The Iframe is not visible until the user clicks a "show" button, but when he does the whole page freezes a second or two until the iframe comes up.
Is it possible to load the iframe in the background without the site freezing up, and if Not, then how can you show a loading gif while the iframe loads?

Comment: How about simply trying it out by yourself, eg on jsfiddle?

Comment: Just need to use jquery, css and animate objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is because iframes loading block certain threads on the browser.
You can read more about it here: [Using Iframes Sparingly | High Performance Web Sites](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/03/using-iframes-sparingly/)

And here are some techniques to load the iframe asynchronously: [Iframe Loading Techniques and Performance - Aaron Peters](https://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-and-performance/)

Comment: Downvoted for a broken link that might have provided the answer to this question. This answer could be helpful if those techniques were at least briefly described here.